# В разделе "Недавние достижения" -> "Вчера" отсутствует значок сворачивания контента

Tags: дефект, статус-не-воспроизводится

В разделе "Недавние достижения" -> "Вчера" отсутствует значок сворачивания ">", хотя раздел можно спокойно сворачивать и разворачивать. см. Рис. ниже. Проанализировал код — оказалось, что там просто отсутствует код (Хотя это может быть сделано специально):

```
<a class="date-group-toggle"></a>
```

[image: Ошибка при сворачивании раздела "Недавние достижения"->"Вчера"]

Comment: Проверил, сейчас не воспроизводится.

Comment: @NickVolynkin уже давно исправили